# Assign class to First Nolan row of every matrix row

Tags: ee2, matrix, nolan

I tried and was unsuccessful in writing a conditional for assigning a class to first Nolan row of every matrix row.

Any pointers on the conditional?

Answer (score 0):

Seems Nolan has a count tag:

`{nolan_row_count} - Same as {count} to avoid variable clashes`

So use

```
{If nolan_row_count ==1}
... do stuff
{/if}
```